# Difference in storage space requirement for TinyText and Text - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, types

In the MySQL manual **Data Type Storage Requirements**, I found:

```
Data Type   Storage Required
--------------------------------------------
TINYTEXT    L + 1 bytes, where L < 2^8  
TEXT        L + 2 bytes, where L < 2^16
```

1. If I store 240 characters [utf8-general] in TinyText and also in the Text field the Text field will just eat 1 byte more than the TinyText?
2. How much space Text will take if I store 1024 letters [utf8-general]?
   *I think 1024+2 bytes*!
3. Will it eat same space if I save a single character or 2^16 characters in a Text field?

Comment: Why do you think that 1 character in UTF-8 takes 1 byte?

Comment: Tinytext eats L+1 bytes, and Text eats L+2 bytes, so ((L+2)-(L+1))=1 byte

Comment: [Data Type Storage Requirements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html#idm140329787061440) docs mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The TinyText can only store up to 255 bytes.  That could be as few as 63 characters if you were so unfortunate as to have to store 63 characters that all required 4 bytes in UTF-8.  One the other hand, it could store 255 characters if they are all, in fact, in the ASCII subset of UTF-8.
2. If you store 1024 characters, they will take between 1024 and 4096 (+2) bytes.  A Unicode character encoded using UTF-8 will occupy between 1 and 4 bytes.
3. A single character requiring one byte (U+0000 .. U+007F) will require 3 bytes (1 for the character, 2 for the length) in a Text field.  On the other hand, a single character requiring 4 bytes (say U+101001 - I'm not sure that's valid as a Unicode character, but it needs 4 bytes to store it) will require a grand total of 6 bytes to store it.  In neither case is it close to 2^16 bytes.

Do learn to distinguish between bytes and characters when dealing with Unicode; it is very important.

Answer (score 3):

Q1: yes
Q2: impossible to answer. Each character in utf-8 can take 1 to 6 bytes. So it will take `1024+2 .. 6144+2` bytes
Q3: nope

Comment: i did not know about **Each character in utf-8 can take 1 to 6 bytes. So it will take 1024+2 .. 6144+2 bytes** , can you explain a little bit more ? when it uses 1 and when it uses 6 bytes with atleast a single example ?

Comment: @Sourav: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8 --- each character has its own "code". So "A" takes 1 byte, "∞" (infinity char) takes 2 bytes, etc

Comment: @Sourav: Unicode is a 21-bit character set and only needs at most 4 bytes to store one character (code point) in UTF-8.